# 'attr_accessible' effects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, methods, attr-accessible

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9 and I would like to know in which cases (that is, for which methods) the `attr_accessible` method has effect. For example, if I use

```
attr_accessible :name, :surname
```

it will care to not assign those attribute values when you use the `new(...)` method for the `User.new(params[:user])` statement.

But **what other methods it will take care?** *Can I run correctly, for example, methods as `where(...)` and `exists?(...)` without that the `attr_accessible` will take effect?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `attr_accessible`, the model will prevent mass assignment of those columns which are not included in the `attr_accessible` list. The methods affected are those of `mass assignment` like `new`, `create`, `update_attributes`, `attributes=` etc. All other functions will work, even single assignment like this:

```
@model_object.column_not_listed_in_attr_accessible_list = "Saved"
@model_object.column_not_listed_in_attr_accessible_list
=> "Saved"
```

So, there should not be any problem for using them in `where`, `exists?` etc.

Answer (score 2):

`attr_accessible` will impact only functions that is related to write operations.

Ex: new, create, update_attributes, etc.

Other read-only functions like where, exists?, etc should not have any impact.

Comment: For an '@users.update_all(...)' method how can I assign a not 'attr_accessible' attribute value?

Comment: @backo...For User.update_all, the SQL is directly sent to the database without instantiation of model objects, so `attr_accessible` or `attr_protected` will have no effect here..it will be saved..see [update_all](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all)...`This method constructs a single SQL UPDATE statement and sends it straight to the database. It does not instantiate the involved models and it does not trigger Active Record callbacks or validations.`